# How to solve a logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

I'm stumble upon the following logarithm expression. What is the value of $x$ in it? $$\log_x (x^5) = 5$$

Comment: For any $x\in(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ the equality holds.

Comment: Anything but 1, at 1 we divide by 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

By definition, $y=\log_b(a)$ if $a=b^y$ for $b\ne 1$.

Here, we have $b=x$, $y=x$, and $a=x^5$.

What can you conclude now?

Comment: Then it'll be X^5 = X^5. Both will cancel out. So 1=1.

Comment: Actually, $x^5=x^5$ for all $x$.  However, we need to have $x^5>0$ and $x\ne 1$.  And that is that.  ;-))

Comment: Still no clue. How do I get x here?

Comment: $x$ can be any non-negative number except for $1$.